# How do you deserialize a JSON Array with multiple types using GSON?

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a JSON String as follows

```
{
"sort": [1000.0, "id123456789"]
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize this JSON String into an Object using `GSON.fromJson(str, SortArray.class)` but I don't know what to do since the JSON Array contains a `double` and a `String`, which are two different types.

Does anyone know how I could model this array in a class so I can deserialize it?

I have tried the following but it does not work

```
@Gson.TypeAdapters(nullAsDefault = true)
@Value.Immutable
public interface SortArray {

@Value.Parameter
double sortScore();

@Value.Parameter
String id();

}
```

Comment: Do the positions of the value (`1000.0` at index 0, `"id123456789"` at index 1) determine the meaning and type of the value? If so there is probably no other solution than to implement a custom `TypeAdapter` (or see if any community library handles this). If not, then what kind of values can this array contain? Maybe you could just deserialize it as `List<Object>`. Also just to be sure, `@Gson.TypeAdapters` comes from https://github.com/immutables/immutables, right?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea I was going with. So when I wrote the SortArray class, I tried with using the positiions of the 2 elements being the type of the value, but that doesn't seem to be working, so I was wondering how I could deserialize it correctly.  `List<Object>` might work.. The array only contains a double and a String. And yes, that annotation comes from Immutables.

Comment: If your `SortArray` only has the `sortScore` and `id` value though, then writing a `TypeAdapter` for it might be the cleaner approach; it would also not be that verbose.